# git svn rebase erroring out all of a sudden

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

We have a relatively standard SVN server in our office, and I've been using Git-SVN with it on my local machine for the past several months without a problem. Nothing in the configuration (both on the server and on my computer) has changed in some time. This morning I went to do a `git svn rebase`, just like I do each morning, and was met with this error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/Core.pm line 584.
Network connection closed unexpectedly: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.:  at /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.8.3/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 2693
```

`git svn fetch` returned the same message as well. Other people in my office (using plain SVN) are still able to connect to it without a problem.

I'm using Lion (10.7.2), git 1.7.8.3, svn 1.6.16, all installed through homebrew. Googling turned up next to nothing useful on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's typically a sign that your network is down or that you cannot connect to the git server. Make sure that your connection to git is good, one of the ways is by pinging the server.

How do I know this?
I tried this out in a test environment where I sockitfy'ed git through a proxy, tried pushing, and it worked.

I tried it with the proxy server off and that exact error was thrown.

Tried it with it turned on again, and the error went away.

Comment: What ended up being the problem (I forgot to update this) was that I had a entry in my `/etc/hosts` file that was causing conflicts with the SVN server. You're basically right on in this. My own fault :)